# Why vscode is having trouble saving a java file ? Which setting should I review?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

In vs code I hit Ctr+N and then Ctr+Shift+S,which is the sortcut for the 'save as' option . When I try to save a file as .java , it saved automatically as class file.Of course this also happens when I try to save the file without using the sortucts,so the only way to create a java file is after the creation of a txt file. Did anyone ever had the same problem with me ? thank you all in advance .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you act like this?

New a file -> Save -> In the 'Save as type' drop-down list select 'Java'.

If you look at it, you will find this: Java(*.class; *.java; *.jav; *.java; *.jav). And the '*.class' was before the '*.java', this means the file will be saved with the '.class' filename extension.

It's caused by the VSCode, but for now, you need manually to change the filename extension when you save the file.

Comment: Thanks mate ! But this is not really solving my problem . My problem is that when I try to save it manually , choosing the java option from the drop-down menu, the file is saved as a class file . Is it a vscode setting that is causing this? Because I dont remember me changing any.

Comment: Yes, and you need to modify the filename extension manually, change the '.class' to '.java' for now. I put a feature request in GitHub, you can follow up it: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/105463